# Using subprocess.call from python that contains escaped characters

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, sql-loader

am triggering SQL loader from a python script (2.7);

The password does contain an `@` sign. If I call sql loader from the command line and escape the password `(username/\"p@ssword\"@database)` the process works. However, when I apply what I believe is the same logic within a python script I get an error:

> SQL*Loader-704: Internal error: ulconnect: OCIServerAttach [0]
>
> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Since I can run the same command in the cmd prompt successfully,  I don't believe this is an issue with the `TNSNAMES.ORA` file containing any incorrect or missing parameters. I'm pretty confident this is an issue with calling SQL loader from the subprocess command and the escape characters.

Python Logic:

```
subprocess.call("sqlldr userid=" +config.ddw["user"] + "/\"" + 
config.ddw["password"] +"\"@" + config.ddw["connection"] + " 
control=C:/projects/controlFile.ctl log=C:/logFile.log)
```

If I print this statement the string looks like:

```
sqlldr userid=USERNAME/"p@ssw0rd"@connection/db 
 (2.7)control=C:/projects/controlFile.ctl log=C:/logFile.log
```

When I load the string directly in the command line it works:

```
sqlldr userid=USERNAME/\"p@ssw0rd\"@connection/db 
control=C:/projects/controlFile.ctl log=C:/logFile.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You need those double-quotes escaped so sqlldr sees them.  I don't know python, but it appears you need to change that code to make sure you get a backslash in front of the double-quotes.  You may need to escape the backslash too since it is most likely a special character.

Perhaps something like this?

```
subprocess.call("sqlldr userid=" +config.ddw["user"] + "/\\"" + 
config.ddw["password"] +"\\"@" + config.ddw["connection"] + "
```

This is a SWAG so your mileage may vary a little :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. I decided to just change how data was being imported. I was on a time crunch and needed a solution fast.